# Are there any other dynamic iOS icons besides the calendar app?

Tags: iphone, ios, icon

The iOS Calendar app dynamically changes every day, showing the current date and weekday. Are there any other dynamic icons, either provided by Apple or 3rd parties?

I'm not talking about the little red circle in the corner letting you know how many updates there are, but rather the entire icon. Jail-broken examples would be interesting, but I'm more interested in jailed examples.

Answer (score 3):

The clock icon is dynamic since iOS 7.

Answer (score 2):

I don't have any jailed examples, I am sorry. AFAIK, it's not possible.